# Document Outline VS2008 for classes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, outline

Is there a sort of class outline window in VS2008?

I have checked the document outline, but it's not for classes. Then there's the class view window, but it shows you everything. I'm searching for something similar like Outline in Eclipse where you can see all fields, properties, methods of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio, right click on project, and select View Diagram. You will get what you are looking for.

In case you have very large project, I mean your project contains lot of classes. The view will of classes will be very small.

To enlarge the view use "ctrl + scroll mouse". I do not know other trick yet :(